# SQLite Database creating problems with my code

Tags: android, sqlite

First time ever using `SQLite`, I have been using an online tutorial which show me how to create a database and a table. My table should have 3 columns of TEXT type which are name, email and password. 
Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work, and I really don't know why, i think it's due to this error

`Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE_TABLE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE_TABLE Registered_Info(UserName TEXT,Password TEXT,Email TEXT);`

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.wolfe_000.final_final_zeno;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by wolfe_000 on 19/04/2015.
 */
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static int database_version = 1;
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE_TABLE "+ TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME+" TEXT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS+" TEXT,"+TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL+" TEXT);";



public DatabaseOperations(Context context){
    super(context, TableData.TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME,null,database_version);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Database Created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb){
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "Database Created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

}

public void putInformation(DatabaseOperations dop, String name, String pass, String email){
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME, name);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS, pass);
    cv.put(TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL, email);
    long k = SQ.insert(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME,null, cv);
    Log.d("Database Operations", "One Raw Inserted");
}
```

}

The error occurs when I click my SignUp button using this code:

```
public void SignUpOnClick(View view ){
    user_name = USER_NAME.getText().toString();
    user_email = USER_EMAIL.getText().toString();
    user_pass = USER_PASS.getText().toString();

    DatabaseOperations DB = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
    DB.putInformation(DB, user_name, user_email, user_pass);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: it's CREATE TABLE not CREATE_TABLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here : `CREATE TABLE`  not `CREATE_TABLE`

```
public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+ TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_NAME+" TEXT,"+ TableData.TableInfo.USER_PASS+" TEXT,"+TableData.TableInfo.USER_EMAIL+" TEXT);";
```

Answer (score 2):

"`CREATE TABLE`" not "`CREATE_TABLE`"  !!!!!